# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x

im getting this for some reason. Im trying to enter the integer 69 instead of "69"
heres the code.

```
number = 69
print("the number im trying to type is" + number + ". ")
```

Comment: `print("the number im trying to type is" + str(number) + ". ")` or use `str.format()`

Comment: If you are using a recent enough python version: `print(f'the number is {number}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So make it a string:

```
number = '69'
number = str(69)
```

or use the format string:

```
number = 69
print("the number is {0}".format(number)) # the number is 69
```

You could also format it in this case, e.g.:

```
number = 69
print("the number is {0:04d}".format(number)) # the number is 0069
```

Comment: thanks, im new to programming, ill have to check out this formatting thing.

Comment: There are a lot of good tutorials. E.g. check https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format